# Return values in an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an assignment that I cannot figure out where my mistake lies. I have a large array of hashes all under the method twitter_data. The hash is structured as such.

```
def twitter_data
[{"User"=>
   {"description"=>
     "Description here",
    "last twenty tweets"=>
     ["tweets written out here"],
    "number of followers"=>1000,
    "number of friends"=>100,
    "latest tweet"=>
     "tweet written out here",
    "number of tweets"=>1000,
    "location"=>"Wherever, Wherever"}},]
end
```

Now if I wanted to for instance list all of the users and their descriptions I thought the code would read as such.

```
twitter_data.each do |twitter_data|
  puts "#{twitter_data[:twitter_data]}: #{twitter_data[:description]}"
end
```

But the output for that just gives me about seven :, without the username in front of it or the description afterwards.

Comment: Using the same variable name for the collection as well as the item (`twitter_data`) is certainly confusing.  Which field under `User` defines the user's name?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the `description` key is nested into another hash which key is `User`. I don't know which is the other key you want to print because data seems incomplete but if you wanted to print just the descriptions this one should work

```
twitter_data.each do |user_data|
  description = user_data["User"]["description"]
  puts description
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons why this does not work:

1) The `twitter_data` element inside the `each` looks like this `{ 'User' => { 'description'...`. On that hash, the value stored under the `:description` key is nil.

2) Even if you where to refer to the correct hash via `twitter_data['User']` you would still be using symbols (e.g. `:description`) instead of strings. So even then, the value stored for the keys would be nil.

3) You are referencing elements that do not seem to exist in the hash even if one where to use strings (e.g. `:twitter_data`). Now this might simply be due to the example selected.

What will work is to correctly reference the hashes:

```
twitter_data.each do |data|
  user_hash = data['User']
  puts "#{user_hash['twitter_data']}: #{user_hash['description']}"
end
```